# add jointable "catalog_product_entity" It get error Can't retrieve entity config

Tags: magento

I modified a module ordergrid to add a column, "provider", that load a attribute from product. I added jointable('catalog_product_entity_int') to the code and I got a 
**Can't retrieve entity config: sales/catalog_product_entity_int**

I have read about the same problem but these cases happens with new tables or blocks. I checked config.xml of another module that uses attributes from products and it does not declare anything about catalog_product_entity.

I assume is a declaration of xml problem but I did some changes and did not get anything.

Some idea??

Thanks.

Comment: Try to do jointable('catalog/product_entity_int') instead of jointable('catalog_product_entity_int') ...

Comment: Thanks, I just checked that but the error was (is) the same but with catalog/product_entity_int

Comment: try to use ->getSelect()->join() instead of ->jointable(), and provide it with "catalog_product_entity_int".

Comment: Thanks Sveta, finally it works, I tried you write. The concret code :$collection->getSelect()->join(array('att'=> Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_int')), ... others parametres